# Use elimination to find the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The problem states:
Use elimination to find the determinant of the matrix
$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}{}
      1&1/2&0&0\\
      0&4&4&8\\
-2&2&3&0\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$

So am I supposed to use elimination, get it to a triangular form and multiply the numbers on the diagonal? If so, which row operations do I use for accomplishing that? Thank you in advance!
 (EDIT)
After elimination the upper triangular matrix I get is:
$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}{}
      1&1/2&0&0\\
      0&4&4&8\\
      0&0&1&-5\\
      0&0&0&-6\\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$
However, the determinant of this is -24 and the answer that I am supposed to get is 24 (found out via calculator), or so I think. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Do classical Gauss elimination but if you want to multiply any row , you have to multiply the whole determinant with that scalar. If you want to be sure you calculated the determinant correctly, use some online determinant calculator. What is your solution anyway?

Comment: Why don't you write *your* solution, John, so *we* can compare and make sure?

Comment: Alright. I added in the result that I got.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's $24$.

$$ 
    \begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
-2&2&3&0\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
0&3&3&0\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
0&0&0&-6\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
0&0&1&-11\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
0&0&1&-11\\
0&0&0&6\\
    \end{bmatrix}.$$

Alternatively, when you get to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&1/2&0&0\\
 0&4&4&8\\
0&0&0&-6\\
0&0&1&-5\\
    \end{bmatrix},
$$
swap the two last lines, but take note of a change of sign.

Comment: Why does the sign change whenever I swap the last 2 rows?

Comment: @JohnShanks: Which matrix would you multiply with to switch two rows?  Then use the multiplicative property for determinants.

Comment: Just to make @mathreadler's suggestion explicit, you swap the last two rows multiplying on the left by
$$\begin{bmatrix}{}
 1&0&0&0\\
 0&1&0&0\\
 0&0&0&1\\
 0&0&1&0\\
    \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: That is what I did, I am just confused by the sign change that mathreadler mentioned. If I exchange rows do I need to change the sign of the determinant? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, because $\det\left( \begin{bmatrix}{}0&1\\  1&0\\     \end{bmatrix} \right) = -1$.

Comment: It is actually a reflection. Imagine the matrix block Andreas mentions in 2D. Switching x and y axes is the same as reflecting in the line $x=y$ and each reflection always switches the sign of the determinant.